Several outs instead of one while applying a function to df
I'm running a script in Jupyter which is expected to show a progressbar while applying a function to a df. In 'out' I see several bars instead of expected one.
I tried to clear 'out' with
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
but it increases time significantly.
When I create a df with less rows, say 100 - there is only one bar.
When I increase the number of rows, the bars appear more times.
What is the problem, please?
out screenshot
import pandas as pd
import math

iterator_for_progressbar = 1

def progressBar(current, total, barLength = 20):
    percent = math.ceil(float(current) * 100 / total)
    arrow   = '■' * int(percent/100 * barLength)
    spaces  = '□' * (barLength - len(arrow))
    print('Calculating: %s%s %d %%' % (arrow, spaces, percent), end='\r')

def myf(row):
    global iterator_for_progressbar
    progressBar(iterator_for_progressbar, len(df), barLength = 20)   
    iterator_for_progressbar += 1

    row['1'] = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0, 5000), columns = ['1','2','3','4','5'] )

df.apply(myf, axis=1)[enter image description here]


"I tried to clear 'out' with import sys sys.stdout.flush() but it increases time significantly." One solution you can apply here is to update the progress bar less often. e.g. you could check if current % 100 == 0, and only update the progress bar if enough iterations have passed.

You could use the tqdm library for the progress bar instead of creating your own.

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm for the Jupyter version.
tqdm.pandas integrates with pandas operations.

def myf(row):
    row['1'] = 100
    return row

tqdm.pandas(desc="Calculating")
df = df.progress_apply(myf, axis=1)

